# Serialization Exception on spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serializable

I meet a very strange problem on Spark about serialization.
The code is as below:

```
class PLSA(val sc : SparkContext, val numOfTopics : Int) extends Serializable
{
    def infer(document: RDD[Document]): RDD[DocumentParameter] = {
      val docs = documents.map(doc => DocumentParameter(doc, numOfTopics))
      docs
    }
}
```

where Document is defined as:

```
class Document(val tokens: SparseVector[Int]) extends Serializable
```

and DocumentParameter is:

```
class DocumentParameter(val document: Document, val theta: Array[Float]) extends Serializable

object DocumentParameter extends Serializable
{
  def apply(document: Document, numOfTopics: Int) = new DocumentParameter(document, 
    Array.ofDim[Float](numOfTopics))
}
```

SparseVectoris a serializable class in `breeze.linalg.SparseVector`.

This is a simple map procedure, and all the classes are serializable, but I get this exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

But when I remove the `numOfTopics` parameter, that is:

```
object DocumentParameter extends Serializable
{
  def apply(document: Document) = new DocumentParameter(document, 
    Array.ofDim[Float](10))
}
```

and call it like this:

```
val docs = documents.map(DocumentParameter.apply)
```

and it seems OK.

Is type Int not serializable? But I do see that some code is written like that.

I am not sure how to fix this bug.

**#UPDATED#**:

Thank you @samthebest. I will add more details about it.

```
stack trace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:270)
    at com.topicmodel.PLSA.infer(PLSA.scala:13)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
    at <init>(<console>:45)
    at .<init>(<console>:49)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1062)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:616)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:954)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 46 more
```

As the stack trace gives the general information of exception, I removed it.

I run the code in the spark-shell.

```
// suppose I have get RDD[Document] for docs
val numOfTopics = 100
val plsa = new PLSA(sc, numOfTopics)
val docPara = plsa.infer(docs)
```

Could you give me some tutorials or tips on serializable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anonymous functions serialize their containing class. When you `map {doc => DocumentParameter(doc, numOfTopics)}`, the only way it can give that function access to `numOfTopics` is to serialize the `PLSA` class. And that class can't actually be serialized, because (as you can see from the stacktrace) it contains the `SparkContext` which isn't serializable (Bad Things would happen if individual cluster nodes had access to the context and could e.g. create new jobs from within a mapper).

In general, try to avoid storing the `SparkContext` in your classes (edit: or at least, make sure it's very clear what kind of classes contain the `SparkContext` and what kind don't); it's better to pass it as a (possibly `implicit`) parameter to individual methods that need it. Alternatively, move the function `{doc => DocumentParameter(doc, numOfTopics)}` into a different class from `PLSA`, one that really can be serialized.

(As multiple people have suggested, it's possible to keep the `SparkContext` in the class but marked as `@transient` so that it won't be serialized. I don't recommend this approach; it means the class will "magically" change state when serialized (losing the `SparkContext`), and so you might end up with NPEs when you try to access the `SparkContext` from inside a serialized job. It's better to maintain a clear distinction between classes that are only used in the "control" code (and might use the `SparkContext`) and classes that are serialized to run on the cluster (which must not have the `SparkContext`)).

Comment: Thank you. It works as you suggested. Also, I find another way to solve this problem: add `@transient` before `val sc : SparkContext`, then `SparkContext` will not be serialized.

Comment: I don't agree that you should avoid storing the `SparkContext` in your classes entirely (but upvoted nevertheless).  If you don't store these in scope then you can end up getting parameter bloat (which is ugly even when using implicit params).  The only alternative is to stick in it some global singleton somewhere which creates problems of it's own (dreaded null pointers).

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a weird one, but I think I can guess the problem.  But first, you have not provided the bare minimum to solve the problem (I can guess, because I've seen 100s of these before).  Here are some problems with your question:

```
def infer(document: RDD[Document], numOfTopics: Int): RDD[DocumentParameter] = {
  val docs = documents.map(doc => DocumentParameter(doc, numOfTopics))
}
```

This method doesn't return `RDD[DocumentParameter]` it returns `Unit`. You must have copied and pasted code incorrectly.

Secondly you haven't provided the entire stack trace? Why? There is no reason NOT to provide the full stack trace, and the full stack trace with message is necessary to understand the error - one needs the whole error to understand what the error is.  Usually a not serializable exception tells you **what** is not serializable.

Thirdly you haven't told us where method `infer` is, are you doing this in a shell? What is the containing object/class/trait etc of `infer`?

Anyway, I'm going guess that by passing in the `Int` your causing a chain of things to get serialized that you don't expect, I can't give you any more information than that until you provide the bare minimum code so we can fully understand your problem.