# Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext - when using JdbcRDD in Spark

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, apache-spark

I am trying to load a RDD from a Mysql database:

```
package ro.mfl.employees
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager}

import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD

class Loader(sc: SparkContext) {

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()

  def connection(): Connection = {
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees", "sakila", "sakila")
  }


  def load(): Unit = {
    val employeesRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc, connection, "select * from employees.employees", 0, 0, 1)
    println(employeesRDD.count())

  }

}

object Test extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val l = new Loader(sc)
  l.load()
}
```

When I execute this, I get an error saying

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@323a9221)
    - field (class: ro.mfl.employees.Loader, name: sc, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class ro.mfl.employees.Loader, ro.mfl.employees.Loader@607c6d60)
    - field (class: ro.mfl.employees.Loader$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class ro.mfl.employees.Loader)
    - object (class ro.mfl.employees.Loader$$anonfun$1, <function0>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$JdbcRDD$$getConnection, type: interface scala.Function0)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD, JdbcRDD[0] at JdbcRDD at Loader.scala:17)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (JdbcRDD[0] at JdbcRDD at Loader.scala:17,<function2>))
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

I tried to make the `Loader` class to extend `java.io.Serializable`, but I got the same error, only with `org.apache.spark.SparkContext` instead of `Loader`.

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` has been obsolete since 2007, and the `.newInstance()` part has never been required. Is this Scala?

Comment: Yes, it is scala. I removed newInstance, same error. I don't understand what was deprecated. I don't see "Class.forName" marked as deprecated in the javadoc.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916852/how-can-i-connect-to-a-postgresql-database-into-apache-spark-using-scala)

Comment: if you are okay with the answer please vote-up as well. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem :

Your issue is `Loader` as `class` which is not `serializable`

try to change it to `object`. or else follow below example given.

```
object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@323a9221)
```

This is because your `Loader` is class and you are passing `SparkContext` to Loader class by creating new instance..

Follow this example(simple and elegant way),this should work:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD
import java.sql.{DriverManager, ResultSet}
// not class enclosed in an object
object LoadSimpleJdbc {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      println("Usage: [sparkmaster]")
      exit(1)
    }
    val master = args(0)
    val sc = new SparkContext(master, "LoadSimpleJdbc", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
    val data = new JdbcRDD(sc,
      createConnection, "SELECT * FROM panda WHERE ? <= id AND ID <= ?",
      lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 3, numPartitions = 2, mapRow = extractValues)
    println(data.collect().toList)
  }
/** createConnection - Get connection here **/
  def createConnection() = {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=holden");
  }
/** This returns tuple **/
  def extractValues(r: ResultSet) = {
    (r.getInt(1), r.getString(2))
  }
}
```

In general, try to avoid storing the `SparkContext` in your classes.

Also, look at [Serialization Exception on spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579474/serialization-exception-on-spark)

try declare `SparkContext` as `@transient` (some users are using this approach across SO)